# Verificar se o conteudo da div carregou

Tags: jquery, html

É possível saber se o conteúdo dentro da `div` carregou com `jquery`? Igual a `body`.

Eu quero fazer um efeito visual do tipo onde aparece uma imagem de *loading* e só depois que a postagem dentro da `div` for carregada por completo o mesmo será exibido.

Pesquisei no [google](https://www.google.com) mas não acho nada a respeito. Não há como ?

Comment: pode detalhar mais sobre como vc está inserindo os dados na div?

Comment: Você está fazendo uma chamada AJAX e populando essa `div`? Se sim, fica mais fácil fazer isso. Mas dê mais detalhes do que você precisa.

Comment: Posta seu código.

Comment: Quando você diz carregou, seria um tempo de `load` até que o conteúdo da div, predefinido, esteja totalmente visível, como no caso de uma imagem? Ou seria um conteúdo carregado via `js`?

Comment: Exemplo youtube quando um dos videos que fica a lateral é escolhido ele muda o vídeo que está tocando no player.
O meu site está com a mesma estratégia quando uma das postagens que fica ao lado é escolhida, ela será carregada para o a div no centro da página e nessa ação são carregado pugins externos como sistemas de comentários e outros.
Eu gostaria que durante esse período seja exibido só uma imagem de loading.

Comment: Se você está carregando com AJAX, poderia exibir uma mensagem de loading antes da chamada do AJAX, e no Success e Error da chamada você removeria a mensagem.

Answer (score 1):

Olá, 
geralmente quando você faz chamadas como carregar comentários, isso é feito com [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), para que a página não seja recarregada quando fazer a requisição.

Usando o ajax, você pode colocar uma div com um loading quando faz a requisição [dos comentários] e retirá-la quando terminar e popular a div com os comentários.

Segue exemplo abaixo:

HTML

```
<div id="comentarios"><img scr="loading.gif" /><\div>
```

JS

```
 $.ajax({
  url: "loadComentarios.php",
  context: document.body
}).done(function(data) {
  $('#comentarios').html(data);
});
```

Perceba que há uma opção de done no ajax. Isso é chamado quando a requisição termina, e tem como parâmetro o que foi retornado do seu php (no caso, os comentários).
Você retira o loading e substitui pela lista de comentários.